# Referencing Loader after created in Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, loader

I am creating a loop which loadsimages to newly created loaders.  After each loader completes, I'd like to pass it through another function

Here's my loop of loaders where loader_names is an array of my loader names and overlay_files is an array of my file URLs

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < loader_names.length; j++) {
 loader_names[j] = new Loader();
 loader_names[j].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
 loader_names[j].load(new URLRequest(overlay_files[j]));
}
```

Once each image loads I want to overlay the image on a map here's a loop which does just that, only I do not know how to pass loaders into this function as they finish

```
function create_overlays(e:Event):void {
 for (var k:int = 0; k < loader_names.length; k++) {
      overlay_names[k] = new GroundOverlay(loader_names[k],
      new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(46.669, -115.035), new LatLng(48.995,-112.079)));        
 }
}
```

Sorry if this is a bit messy, I am still learning.  I am happy to clarify/simplify any of this..

thanks,

j

Comment: So what's the problem? It seems like you are using your loaders in another function already.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, I misunderstood your issue.

In your create_overlays function you can refer to your loader by using the event that is passed in.

```
e.target
```

will refer you to the loader which fired the event.